# download the dataset in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, download, render, dt

I am new to R shiny and I am going to download the dataset I am looking at but it says "unused argument (mainPanel(dowloadButton("downloadDatable", "Download the Dataset")))". Could you please help me with it? Thanks so much for your help.

```
library(shiny)

# Read the data
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00356/student.zip",
temp, mode="wb")
unzip(temp, "student-mat.csv")
mathdat <- read.table("student-mat.csv",sep= ";", header= T)
unlink(temp)

# UI part

shinyUI(navbarPage(
  title = 'DataTable Options',
  tabPanel('Display length',     DT::dataTableOutput('table.sub_1')),
  tabPanel('Length menu',        DT::dataTableOutput('table.sub_2')),
),
  mainPanel(
    dowloadButton("downloadDatable", "Download the Dataset"))
)

# Server part
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # display 10 rows initially
  output$table.sub_1 <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(mathdat, options = list(pageLength = 25))
  )
  
  # -1 means no pagination; the 2nd element contains menu labels
  output$table.sub_2 <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(
      mathdat, options = list(
        lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), c('5', '15', 'All')),
        pageLength = 15
      )
    )
  )
  
  
  # Download the datatable
  output$downloadDatable <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){paste("Student Performance in Math.csv")},
    content = function(file){write.csv(mathdat(), file, row.names = FALSE)}
  )
  
  
  
})
```

[image]

Comment: Is it a typo, or do you define (somewhere) a similar-named function named `dowloadButton`?

Comment: That specific error is because you are passing a second argument `mainPanel(...)` to `shinyUI`, which accepts a single argument `ui=`. I suggest you look (again) at some of the `shiny` demos in the tutorial or in the gallery to see suggested layouts, including `ui <- ...; server <- ...; shinyApp(ui, server)`, or `app.R` layout, or `ui.R`/`server.R`/`global.R` constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mathdat()` should be `mathdat` in `write.csv(mathdat,file,row.names = FALSE)`, unless you are defining a reactive dataframe somewhere else.